# Regex how to get groups within json expression

Tags: regex, json

Say I have following JSON:

```
{"MyPerson":{"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}},"AnotherComplexObject":{"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"},"Count":1,"Start":2}
```

I remove starting `{` and ending `}` and get:

```
"MyPerson":{"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}},"AnotherComplexObject":{"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"},"Count":1,"Start":2
```

Now, what regex would I use to get "complex objects" out, for example in that JSON I would want to get these two results:

```
{"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}}
{"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"}
```

The closest I've came to solution is this regex `{[^}]*}` but that one fails to select `}` in that `"Number":15` result.

Comment: But...why?  This is like trying to parse HTML with RegEx, there will be edge cases.

Comment: Why don't you just parse the JSON into an object and use that?

Comment: Because it's one way to solve this problem I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492529/how-to-serialize-complex-json-object-to-querystring-for-http-get-using-jackson?rq=1

Comment: Don't use regex to parse json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# String
# "MyPerson":{"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}},"AnotherComplexObject":{"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"},"Count":1,"Start":2

/({[^}]+}})/
# http://rubular.com/r/rupVEn9yZo
# Match Groups
# 1. {"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}}

/({[^}]+})/
# http://rubular.com/r/H5FaoH18c8
# Match Groups
# Match 1
# 1. {"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}
# Match 2
# 1. {"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"}

/({[^}]+}})[^{]+({[^}]+})/
# http://rubular.com/r/zmcyjvoR1y
# Match Groups
# 1. {"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}}
# 2. {"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"}


# String
# {"MyPerson":{"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}},"AnotherComplexObject":{"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"},"Count":1,"Start":2}

/[^{]+({[^}]+}})[^{]+({[^}]+})/
# http://rubular.com/r/qCxN1Rk9Ka
# Match Groups
# 1. {"Firstname":"First","Lastname":"Last","Where":{"Street":"Street","Number":15}}
# 2. {"Another":"Yes","Me":"True"}
```