# Dynamic Json string to Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonnode

How would you map this JSON string with dynamic properties to a Java object?

```
{    
    'name' : 'John',
    'lastname': 'Doe',
    'dynamicProperty1': { 'label' : 'size', 'value': 'large'},
    'dynamicProperty2': { 'label' : 'color', 'value': 'blue'},
    'dynamicProperty3': { 'label' : 'height', 'value': 200},
    'dynamicProperty...': { 'label' : 'points', 'value': 300}
}
```

Comment: As a clarification, you seem to be hinting the properties would be follow a particular naming conventions, but is it safe to assume that you might have any number of unknown fields names?
`...'cat': {...}, 'dog':{...}...`

Comment: Either way if you have control over this data model I'd suggest for simplicity to move all your dynamic properties into a list of instead like `dynamicProperties: [{...},{...},{...}]`

Comment: @hdost, I have no control over the dynamic properties. those dynamic property can go from 0 up to 100.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson deserialization with unknown dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685508/jackson-deserialization-with-unknown-dynamic-properties)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JsonAnySetter` annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HandleDynamicKeysInJsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}

@Data
class Person {
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("lastname")
    private String lastName;

    private Map<String, Label> labels = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addDynamicProperties(String key, Label label) {
        labels.put(key, label);
    }
}

@Data
class Label {
    private String label;
    private Object value;
}
```

- [Jackson deserialization with unknown dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685508/jackson-deserialization-with-unknown-dynamic-properties/17698380#17698380)
- [How to serialize ANY Object into a URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408599/how-to-serialize-any-object-into-a-uri/18411268#18411268)
- [How can I deserialize a JSON to a Java class which has known mandatory fields, but can have several unknown fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081709/how-can-i-deserialize-a-json-to-a-java-class-which-has-known-mandatory-fields-b/57081808#57081808)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a Java class to hold name, lastName and hashmaps to store dynamic properties.
Example -

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   String lastName;
   Map<String,Object> dynamicProperty1;
   Map<String,Object> dynamicProperty2;
   Map<String,Object> dynamicProperty3;
}
```

Or if you have the variable amount of dynamic property maps ( as suggested in the comments), you can do something like below

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   String lastName;
   Map<String,Map<String, Object>> dynamicPropertyMaps;
 }
```

And then inside your mapper class, you can create hashmaps based on the values in JSON and put them in the dynamicPropertyMaps Map.

Comment: This doesn't account for the N possible dynamic properties.

Comment: @hdost if this is that much dynamic, there is no solution other than adding a map of maps. ( i.e Map<String, Map<String, Object>> dynamicPropertyMap). Then in the mapper, we can build map one by one and add them to dynamicPropertyMap

Comment: That would be the answer then. at least as an intermediary.

Comment: @DimuthTharakaMenikgama can you show the code snippet for the mapper using your suggestion? thanks