# ObjectMapper readValue list the unknown properties

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

The readValue() method throw IOException when it's unable to create object of a given type.

How can I get the list of unrecognised fileds?

I don't want to suppress the error by ignoring the unknown fields or using `JsonAlias`

Comment: How about with adding some code, Updating the question, and show the full error log.
before you do that, Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Read about `JsonAnySetter` - [Jackson @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter Example](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter-example) and take a look on the similar questions: [How to serialize ANY Object into a URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408599/how-to-serialize-any-object-into-a-uri), [How to use dynamic property names for a Json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684724/how-to-use-dynamic-property-names-for-a-json-object)